# How to remove metapackage entirely in Debian

Tags: debian, apt, aptitude, synaptic

Is there any way to remove meta package and all its packages? Subset of metapackage is packages which don't depend on metapackage by all means. That's why if remove one metapackage only the package's subset of metapackage is not removed.

For example metapackage `apache2` consists some packages which will be installed if install `apache2`. I used the `apt-get install apache2` command in shell and `synaptic` and I installed some packages. Now if I remove metapackage `apache2` via `apt-get autoremove apache2` command or `synaptic` I remove `apache2` package only and other packages which are a subset of the metapackage are not removed.

In my opinion the best way is to remove all packages within the metapackage. How to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know `apache2` is not a [metapackage](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MetaPackages). Various packages have dependencies so installing `apache2` will also cause other packages to be installed but that does not make them a metapackage.

In any case, I am not sure what exactly you are trying to achieve so I will give you a few options:

1. If you want to remove packages that are no longer needed, for example things that were installed by `apache2` and are no longer necessary now that you have removed it, use `autoremove`:

   ```
   apt-get autoremove
   ```
2. If you really want to remove all packages installed by a true metapackage, you can do something like this (using the `wicd` metapackage as an example):

   i. Find the packages installed by the metapackage by searching through the `apt` log:

   ```
   $ grep -A 3 wicd /var/log/apt/history.log
   Commandline: apt-get install wicd
   Install: rfkill:amd64 (0.4-1, automatic), wicd:amd64 (1.7.2.4-4), python-wicd:amd64 (1.7.2.4-4, automatic), wicd-daemon:amd64 (1.7.2.4-4, automatic), wicd-gtk:amd64 (1.7.2.4-4, automatic)
   End-Date: 2013-05-07  18:10:24
   ```

   ii. You can parse this to get only the package names:

   ```
   $ grep -A 3 wicd /var/log/apt/history.log | 
       perl -ne 's/Install:*// && do {
         @a=(/\s+([^\s]+?):/g); print "@a\n"
        }'  
     rfkill wicd python-wicd wicd-daemon wicd-gtk
   ```

   iii. You can now remove them (I am printing the `apt` command instead of executing it so you can see what it will uninstall first):

   ```
   $ grep -A 3 wicd /var/log/apt/history.log | 
       perl -ne 's/Install:*// && do {
         @a=(/\s+([^\s]+?):/g); print "apt-get remove @a\n"
        }'  
     apt-get remove  rfkill wicd python-wicd wicd-daemon wicd-gtk
   ```